# iPhone/Google contacts switched from Exchange to CardDAV but one way sync only

Tags: contacts, google-sync, carddav

Having read the answers to [Is it better for iOS to sync Gmail contacts using Exchange ActiveSync or the CardDAV protocol?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65527/is-it-better-for-ios-to-sync-gmail-contacts-using-exchange-activesync-or-the-car), I switched off Contacts on the Exchange account, and set up CardDAV following Google instructions. Google is set as the default account on the iPhone. I have nearly instantaneous updates from the iPhone to Google. But I've waited a couple of hours and have yet to see a new contact and an update to an existing contact that I made via web Gmail show up on the phone. Is there a setting I'm missing? Per Google help, I already checked that the Account is on, and that I am using SSL. I'm on iOS 6.0.

Well, seven hours later I have the updates on the phone. Is this the norm?

Comment: To be clear - you had a one-time seven hour delay or is this something that you can reproduce and get a seven hour delay on all contacts?

Comment: I had a one-time seven hour delay, then had other issues with contacts not syncing at all. I reset the iPhone, and it immediately synced all the missing contacts. I haven't had any problems since.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that CardDAV does not push changes from server to clients, but rather requires that clients poll the server. Perhaps you have polling turned off?

1. Launch **Settings**.
2. Select **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.
3. Select **Fetch New Data**.
4. Under the **Fetch** heading, is **Manually** selected? If so, then your phone is not automatically checking for updates.
5. Select **Advanced**.
6. Find your Google CardDAV account in this list. Is it set to **Fetch** or **Manual**? If the latter, then your phone is not automatically checking for updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal. I just set up Google CardDav on my iPhone 4. I was adding a contact to Google that was already in my iPhone. While I was reading the info off my phone and typing it into Gmail, it showed up immediately on my phone.

I can't tell you why your contacts are not updating immediately, but it is definitely not normal.